# Element wise multiplication in CVXPY

Tags: python, python-2.7, cvxpy

I have the following code snippet for CVXPY:

```
delta=1e-3

loglambda = rvec*theta #rvec: TxJ regressor matrix, theta: (Jx1) cvx variable 
a= mul_elemwise(dy[0:T],loglambda) # size(Tx1)
b1=cvx.exp(loglambda) 
b2=mul_elemwise(delta,b1) 
cost= -a + b1             
#cost= -a + b2  #size (Tx1)
prob = Problem(Minimize(sum_entries(cost)))
prob.solve(solver=SCS)
```

The code runs fine as it is with `cost = - a + b1`. However, if I try to multiply `b1` with a scalar using `mul_elemwise` and try to run it with `cost = - a + b2`, I get the error message:

> UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'coeff' referenced before assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is  fixed on the latest master. And I dont need to use  mul_elemwise to multiply by a scalar, delta*b1 it will automatically do the right thing in cvxpy